# what's the shortcut of switching between different perspectives in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, shortcut, perspective

I have PyDev, Java, and CDT installed on my Eclipse, and sometimes I need to switch between different perspectives; **Debug** to **Pydev**, for example. Does Eclipse have a shortcut to switch between them?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

To switch between perspectives.

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

Comment: Now I just need to find a way to remove the perspectives I never need. Hm.

Comment: @ThomasAhle maybe you should open a question, but the answer is: right click over the perspective icon > close

Answer (score 7):

You can specify hotkeys for specific perspectives in Window->Preferences:

[image]

You can export these to file using 'Export CSV...', here are mine if interested -

- http://justinreina.com/misc/17_06_26_eclipse/jmr_hotkeys.csv

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> same as windows

Comment: Any way to do it while retaining focus in the editor window?

Answer (score 1):

Command-F8 lets you change perspectives in Eclipse for Mac.

Comment: How do you do it on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse allows you to change the perspective easily. `Ctrl + F8` still switches between default/regular and most recent perspective. The toolbar shortcut is available too.
[Toolbar shortcut Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0MHE.jpg)